# .htaccess regex won't filter for .php or no file extension

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Trying to set a `.htaccess` file for direct all URLs that end in `.php` or no file extension at all to `index.php`. So URLs like `mysite.com/about` and `mysite.com/news.php` will go to `index.php`, but `mysite.com/someimage.jpg` and `mysite.com/mystyle.css` will be handled normally.

I thought I had it when I tested with regular old PHP but something doesn't seem to be translating in the `.htaccess` file. These are the two rules I've come up with:

```
RewriteRule [A-Za-z0-9]*$ "index.php" [L] # URLs with no extension

RewriteRule [A-Za-z0-9]*\.php$ "index.php" [L] # ending in .php
```

With these rules, files like CSS and images aren't being served, everything is still going to `index.php` so the server will serve `index.php` when the browser asked for a stylesheet. I've tried commenting out the `.php` rule so only the 'no extension' rule is applied, same result. I've tried adding a slash at the beginning like there would be in a URL and that actually breaks things so none of the rules are applied.

What tiny yet obvious detail am I missing here?

Comment: If in doubt, it often helps to enable/peek at the rewrite log - for overlapping/similar rules at least.

Comment: I didn't know about the rewrite log. Just turned it on. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your extensions end in alpha characters so `[A-Za-z0-9]*$` matches the `jpg` of `.jpg` and `css` of `.css`.

I think:

```
RewriteRule (\.php|^[^.]+)$ "index.php" [L]
```

will accomplish what you want. That says if the file ends with `.php` or the full path doesn't have a period in it send it to `index.php`.

https://regex101.com/r/AE8AjY/1/

compared to your regex(s):

https://regex101.com/r/AE8AjY/2/ (combined the two rules into one by making the `.php` optional)

Comment: I think that did it. Thanks! Originally I had rules with `\/` (tried with and without the escape slash) so that anything after the last slash in a URL had to either have .php or nothing but letters and numbers. Like I said though, that just stopped the rules from working at all. Do you know why that might've been?

Comment: The slashes don't need to be escaped in `.htaccess` in PHP they do only if they are used as the delimiter of the regex. Can you post the full regex you were trying? Do you have a base defined in your htaccess file?

Comment: Sure. Initially the two rules I was trying were these:
`RewriteRule /[a-zA-Z0-9]*$ "index.php"`
`RewriteRule /[a-zA-Z0-9]*\.php$ "index.php"`
When they didn't work was when I started trying to escape and doing other stuff. There's no defined base in htaccess, no. I only cared about what was going on after the last slash in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

1. Main problem is not using start anchor in your rules.
2. Rules can be further optimized.

Have it this way:

```
RewriteEngine On

# ignore index.php
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ [L,NC]

# URLs with no extension OR URLs ending with .php
RewriteRule ^[\w-]+(?:\.php)?$ index.php [L,NC]
```